# What to use, Excel or database for data driven framework in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

I am working on Selenium automation using WebDriver. It is keyword and data driven approach. I am handling all the inputs of objects,data and test configuration from Microsoft Excel.

Now client want to use database. He is asking me which one is more good to use in framework. Either database or Microsoft Excel utility? I have to reply to him with valid points.

Which one is the better to use in framework and also why second one is not good to use?

Answer (score 3):

This question really requires an opinionated answer, but because there are some important benefits from one or the other I will still answer it!

With Excel, data entry is easy and accessible to non-technical testers. It has good sorting ability and the data can be organised in a pretty intuitive fashion. However, you cannot add or alter data during a test easily (I understand you could do this but I would this this is overboard). This means data must be previously organised and specific to the test requirements.

In a database data can come from queries and be altered on the fly. You could write helper functions that populate required data if it can't be found in the db. This means tests can run without worrying about what data is currently in the db (to an extent) and can alleviate some project issues. However, with a database there can be issues importing/exporting and there could be a lot of coding overhead. Also, obviously non-technical testers will find it hard to change the data.

As I said this is really an opinion in the end and is very much a project by project decision.

Comment: +1, a lot of comes down to how 'technical' the testers are. If they feel comfortable with a database and SQL, then I would choose the database since it gives you a lot more freedom and power with your tests.

Comment: Also adding one more point excel is pretty much limited to windows but with database you can use it on any platform. Also accessing database located on a server is easier than an excel located on a server.

Answer (score 0):

With my experience efficiency plays an integral role comparing these too approaches. Using a database tend to slow down the performance unlike excel sheets. Using a file(excel) increases the efficiency. And in our company automations suits we rarely use databases. Instead will push data in to files and use them as the repository.